# Keyframes for seperate objects appear linked in dope sheet post-seperation

Tags: keyframes

I'm animating curves with the Start and End Bevel parameters in the curve options. I have a letter sequence that has to repeat a tracing effect on each letter in succession, one at a time, left to right.

So I joined the curves for this sequence of letters into one curve object, set the directions for each letter, and then keyframed the Start and End Bevel over a few frames for a tracing effect. I then separated each letter into its own object.

Great! Now I don't have to keyframe specifically the same thing for each letter and can just drag over the start/end keyframes for each letter .. But wait. Now I'm trying to move those Start/End keyframes in the dope sheet to create the letter by letter effect, and each keyframe wants to move with every other letter, as if they were somehow linked, even though they're separate curve objects now.

The idea is I could save time by doing the letter by letter animation by only by moving the keyframes for each object in the dope sheet. I'm also concerned why things are linked in the dope sheet. I literally cannot animate! [image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you post a .blend-file reduced to the problem using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or edit your question and add steps recreating the problem? That would make answering your question easier as one does not have to guess.

Comment: Hi. I uploaded the file in a new post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131706/how-to-unlink-seperated-objects-keyframes here. I've been using Blender for 12 years and I find this website more difficult to navigate.