# How to unlink seperated objects keyframes?

Tags: keyframes

I posted this earlier but comments don't allow me to post attachments.

I want the bottom object to animate 20 frames later than the top one. They will not let me do that in the dope sheet; every object's keyframes moves when I try to edit keyframes in the dope sheet. Attached is the .blend.

The problem: two objects keyframes copy each others's modifications. How to separate the two?

https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/781641/ProblemFile.blend

Comment: Ok I've deleted my answer as it was not satisfying, and your file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iefjk7wxex945hz/ProblemFile.blend?dl=0